# Copy files from multiple hosts to one network share. Python

Tags: python, linux, rsync, nfs

I have one python script which calling linux rsyslog command with subprocess module and copying files from multiple hosts to one network share. Script should start at the same time on all hosts by cron. But the main issue is how can the script run orderly. Example:
Host1, Host2, Host3, Host 4 are copying files to nfs01.
Script starts at 8 AM by cronjob on all hosts. It should first start on Host1 and start copying. Script which started on Host2, Host3 and Host4 should understand Host1 still copying files and when it finished copying, Host2 should start and Host3-4 should wait. And so on.

Does anyone have any methods for doing it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post your script. So it will be easier to help you.

Comment: The problem is, I want to get the method how to do this. The script is not done yet but there is such type requirement and I was wondering if there is a best practice or known method about this.